# (Only C) conversion special characters from string char to hexadecimal

Tags: c, special-characters

I'm trying to use this code: 
https://www.includehelp.com/c/convert-ascii-string-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c.aspx

This code works perfect on my program. It converts from utf-8 to hexa characters like A,m,n,d,0,9 perfectly.

Please, can anybody tell me or modify this program, when inside the string we have "special characters", like vocals with accents (ñ,ç,à,á,...).
because, when I run this program don't works as I expected.

I'm working in a RHEL 7 with native C (sorry but I don't know the version) The special characters that I'm trying to conver to hex are in UTF-8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//function to convert ascii char[] to hex-string (char[])
void string2hexString(char* input, char* output)
{
    int loop;
    int i; 

    i=0;
    loop=0;

    while(input[loop] != '\0')
    {
        sprintf((char*)(output+i),"%02X", input[loop]);
        loop+=1;
        i+=2;
    }
    //insert NULL at the end of the output string
    output[i++] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char ascii_str[] = "Hello world!";
    //declare output string with double size of input string
    //because each character of input string will be converted
    //in 2 bytes
    int len = strlen(ascii_str);
    char hex_str[(len*2)+1];

    //converting ascii string to hex string
    string2hexString(ascii_str, hex_str);

    printf("ascii_str: %s\n", ascii_str);
    printf("hex_str: %s\n", hex_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
ascii_str: Hello world!

hex_str: 48656C6C6F20776F726C6421
```

I would like entry ascii_str like "ñáéíóúàèìòùç" and be able to obtain this hex codes on a string:

```
letra-> á // cod.hex--> e1
letra-> é // cod.hex--> e9
letra-> í // cod.hex--> ed
letra-> ó // cod.hex--> f3
letra-> ú // cod.hex--> fa
letra-> à // cod.hex--> e0
letra-> è // cod.hex--> e8
letra-> ì // cod.hex--> ec
letra-> ò // cod.hex--> f2
letra-> ù // cod.hex--> f9
letra-> ç // cod.hex--> e7
```

Comment: How exactly are `m` and `n` classified as "hexa characters"???

Comment: character-> m // code--> 0x006d | character -> n // code--> 0x006e. Why do you need this codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
sprintf((char*)(output+i), "%02X", input[loop]);
```

To this (which solves your problem):

```
sprintf((char*)(output+i), "%02X", (unsigned char)input[loop]);
```

Or better yet, to this (which gets rid of a redundant cast):

```
sprintf(output+i, "%02X", (unsigned char)input[loop]);
```

Comment: one moer question, now with this sentence I obtain this hex code  "c3 91" as "Ñ" character but I looking for this hexadecimal code: "F1" that corresponds to unicode. Sorry I didn't tell right my problem.

Comment: @sigsag: Then why did you retract the V??? "I didn't tell right my problem" - then post it as a separate problem; don't change the question after you've accepted the answer!